# Django querying data out of models and get sum of field

Tags: python, django, model

I'm just beginning with Django and have the following question:
I have set up a model looking like

```
class Automation_Apps(models.Model):
    app_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    app_description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    view_function_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    time_saver_min = models.IntegerField()
    implementation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.app_name

class Automation_Usage(models.Model):
    used_app = models.ForeignKey(Automation_Apps, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    used_by_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    used_on_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I would like to query it like:

```
Select Sum(time_saver_min)
from Automation_Apps, Automation_Usage
where Automation_Usage.used_app = Automation_Apps.app_name
```

The goal of this is the following:
`Automation_App` will have the Apps and a field, how much time will be saved by using this app

`Automation_Usage` will have the records, when a user is utilizing the app.

With my query I would like to pull how often the apps where used and how much time was saved by using it (which comes from the `Automation_App`).

I would like to do this in my view.

Comment: What is the goal of query? I suppose, you would like to get sum of `time_saver_min` for a specific `app_name`, but not sure why you included the other model?

Comment: The goal of the query: I want to collect how many users utilize the app. This is in Automation_Usage. But I would like to have the time saved. This information is in Automation_Apps. The result should give me sum of time over all apps utilized. Does this make sense?

Comment: Right! So you would like to get sum of time utilized over all apps by each user? I have added the answer, please review.

Comment: Seems, you also need count of users for each app. I have added two options in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get sum of time utilized over all apps by each user:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
Automation_Usage.objects.values('used_by_user').annotate(time=Sum('used_app__time_saver_min'))
```

To get number of users and sum of time utilized for each app:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Count
Automation_Usage.objects.values('used_app').annotate(users=Count('used_by_user'), time=Sum('used_app__time_saver_min'))
```

Comment: That is it! Thanks so much for your Support!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Model Sum to Sum the value of your model.

Do it this way;

`from django.db.models import Sum`
Then

`data = Model.objects.aggregate(Sum('time_saver_min'))['time_saver_min__sum'] print(data)`

Comment: This is adding the time out of Automation_Apps. But I would like to sum the entries out of Automation_Usage with the value time_saver_min out of Automation_Apps.
I would like to register the usage. For every usage of the app I will get the amount of minutes saved out of Automation_Apps which I would like to sum up, like described in the SQL above.
Example:
I have 3 entries in Automation_Usage. 2 for app 1 and 1 for app 2
In Automation_Apps I have in the field time_saver_min for App 1 =5 min and for App 2 = 10 min
The result of the sum should be 20 min.

Answer (score 1):

You can use annotate in Django ORM.

My solution:

Sum(time_saver_min) based on Automation_Usage.used_app = Automation_Apps.app_name

=>  queryset = Automation_Usage.objects.values('used_app').annotate(Coalesce(Sum('used_app__time_saver_min'), Value(0)))

=> print(queryset['used_app__time_saver_min__sum'])

Comment: Can't get it to run: 'Coalesce' object has no attribute 'filter'

Comment: @OliverDemus I was edited, please check it!